# JBoss application deployment failed with WFLYCTL0288

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm very new to JBoss and trying to deploy my application on  `jboss-eap-7.0` but it failed with error -

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available.\" => {
    \"Services that were unable to start:\" => [
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".component.\\\"com.abc.xy.InitializationServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".component.\\\"com.abc.xy.commonui.components.AjaxTree.Servlets.TreeController\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".component.\\\"com.abc.xy.commonui.components.customlistbox.xyCustomListBoxTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".component.\\\"com.abc.xy.commonui.components.exprbuilder.xyExprBuilderController\\\".START\",

 \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".component.\\\"org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".deploymentCompleteService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"xy.war\\\".ejb3.client-context.registration-service\",
        \"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./xy\",
        \"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./xy.UndertowDeploymentInfoService\"
    ],
    \"Services that may be the cause:\" => [\"jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector\"]
}}"
```

Can someone help to understand how this can be fixed?

Comment: There should be more information in the log files.

Comment: add the lines that come below, it will say the reason

Comment: Added the remaining lines.

Comment: add the config files pls